# Return Observable in canDeactivate not working

Tags: angular, angular2-router3

I have a confirm/cancel modal dialog that pops up when a user leaves a route. I do this by using a guard with the canDeactivate method. However I want canDeactivate to wait until it gets a response from the modal before returning anything.

I have tried to do this by returning an observable but it is not working.

```
canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    if(this.isFormStarted()) {
        this.formService.showExitModal(true);
        return this.formService.getModalSelectionObservable();
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Nothing is happening when I click confirm even though I can see that the observable is working fine when I do a console.log inside the if block

```
this.formService.getModalSelectionObservable().subscribe(
        value => console.log("dialog value: " + value)
    );
```

Here is how the form service looks.

```
private modalConfirmation = new Subject<boolean>();

public setModalSelectionObservable(confirmLeave: boolean) {
    this.modalConfirmation.next(confirmLeave);
}
public getModalSelectionObservable(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.modalConfirmation.asObservable();
}
```

Comment: why is that you are using 2 different services in your `canDeactivate` function: `this.formService` and `this.createFormService`?

Comment: Yeah they should be the same, I've updated it, thanks. I just changed the variable names so that they would make more sense here.

Comment: Hi Mark, how do manage to make your modal waits the user response? could you share your solution? I'm facing the same problem. Kind regards

Comment: I have a service that sets and gets observables. When clicking confirm I call setModalSelectionObservable() and pass in true. 
I then subscribe to getModalSelectionObservable() in my guard service as you can see from the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `take(1)` or `first()` (don't forget to import)

```
return this.formService.getModalSelectionObservable().first();
```

to ensure the observable is closed after the first event, otherwise the router will wait until it is closed from the service.

Comment: Hi Gunter, could you explain me how `getModalSelectionObservable` should work? I'm facing the same problem and I don't know how to make the refresh waits the result from modal.

Comment: I don't know about `getModalSelectionObservable()`. I only know about `canDeactivate`

Comment: I see...I'm facing this problem with canDeactivate...I'm not able to show custom messages or dialog using service... [see my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42142053/candeactivate-confirm-message) ..could help me?

Comment: Maybe is it a typo?: *"Use take(1) (don't forget to import)"*... but you suggest `.first()`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. They both work. I changed to code example from take to first at some point, but forgot to change the text as well.

Answer (score 2):

It was not working on my end because I was using `BehaviorSubject` with initial value `null`.

Make sure to create Observable from `Subject` like:

```
private modalConfirmation = new Subject<boolean>();
public getModalSelectionObservable(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.modalConfirmation.asObservable();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just putting this here in case someone in future is as careless as me:

If your component has a function `hasUnsavedChanges()` your `canDeactivate()` method would need to return `!hasUnsavedChanges()`.

But then if you start using an observable for `hasUnsavedChanges`, you'll be returning `!hasUnsavedChanges$` which will just be a falsey value.

If you need to support both you can do this:

```
canDeactivate(component: C)
{
    var hasUnsavedChanges = component.hasUnsavedChanges();

    if (typeof (hasUnsavedChanges) === 'boolean')
    {
        return !hasUnsavedChanges;
    }
    else
    {
        return hasUnsavedChanges.map(x => !x);
    }
}
```