# CanDeactivate confirm message

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I've implemented a `CanDeactivate` guard to avoid user leave the page during the upload and it works. The problem is that my message is always a default message (in dutch because of the browser language) and, even setting a message myself, still show the same default `confirm` window. I would like to write my own message (actually I have a modal that I want to show, but first I would like to see working just with my simple message)

Any ideas what could it be? Am I missing something?

Here's the code

**Guard.**

```
import { Injectable, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { DialogService } from '../services';
    
export interface PendingUpload {
   canDeactivate: () => boolean | Observable<boolean>;
}
@Injectable()
export class PendingUploadGuard implements CanDeactivate<PendingUpload> {
    constructor(
        private dialogService: DialogService,
        private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef
    ) { }
    
    canDeactivate(component: PendingUpload): boolean | Observable<boolean> { 
        return component.canDeactivate()
           ? true
           : confirm("Test custom message");
           //dialog I want to use later
           //this.dialogService.confirm("modal title", "modal body", this.viewContainerRef);                   
     }
 }
```

**Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { PendingUpload } from '../../shared/validators/pending-upload.guard';

import './../../rxjs-operators';

@Component({
    selector: 'component-selector',
    templateUrl: './html',
    styleUrls: ['./css']
})
export class ScannerUploadComponent implements OnInit, PendingUpload {
    uploading: boolean = false;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.uploading = false;
    }

    @HostListener('window:beforeunload')
    canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {  
        return !this.uploading;
    }
}
```

Comment: Elmer found the anders to this question here: [Angular 2 - Warn user of unsaved changes before leaving page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35922071/angular-2-warn-user-of-unsaved-changes-before-leaving-page/)

Comment: I've seen this and still gives me a default message text (in dutch) instead of my custom message....I use the specific guard from Angular docs and works but has a bug like [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10321)..I'm struggling to make this work but with no sucess until now.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your custom message will only be shown when trying to navigate elsewhere **within your Angular app** (e.g., navigating from http://localhost:4200/#/test1 to http://localhost:4200/#/test2). This is because the `CanDeactivate` guard only activates for route changes made via the Angular router, within your Angular app.

When navigating **away from your Angular app** (e.g., navigating from http://localhost:4200/#/test1 to http://stackoverflow.com, refreshing the page, closing the browser window/tab, etc.), the `window` `beforeunload` event activates (due to the `@HostListener('window:beforeunload')` annotation) and handles the `confirm` dialog on its own, without the `CanDeactivate` guard. In this case, Chrome and Firefox display their own pending changes warning message.

You can read more about the `beforeunload` event and how it works [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload). You'll notice in the "Notes" section that it states the following:

> In Firefox 4 and later **the returned string is not displayed to the user**. Instead, Firefox displays the string "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved."

Chrome follows a similar pattern, explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37782307/7307355).

IE/Edge still seem to offer the ability to specify a custom `beforeunload` message. An example of this can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42108319/7307355).

Comment: Thanks for answering, Stew!! I've already had read about the beforeunload event and see that is not possible to customize message when using it. I thought that I was doing something wrong because in your answer (from the link you've posted) none of this was mention it so...I was trying to do the impossible =]. At least now I know that I was on the right path. Thanks again.

Comment: @ElmerDantas - no problem. I've now updated my answer to the other question to state this distinction. Sorry for the confusion.