# Warning before leaving page - but not if route matches

Tags: angular

I have implemented the following method for warning a visitor before leaving a form:

**pending-changes.guard.ts:**

```js
import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export interface ComponentCanDeactivate {
  canDeactivate: () => boolean | Observable<boolean>;
}

@Injectable()
export class PendingChangesGuard implements CanDeactivate<ComponentCanDeactivate> {
  canDeactivate(component: ComponentCanDeactivate): boolean | Observable<boolean> {

  // if there are no pending changes, just allow deactivation; else confirm first
  return component.canDeactivate() ?
    true :
    // NOTE: this warning message will only be shown when navigating elsewhere within your angular app;
    // when navigating away from your angular app, the browser will show a generic warning message
    // see http://stackoverflow.com/a/42207299/7307355
    confirm('WARNING: You will have to re-choose any images if you go back. Press Cancel to stay on the page, or OK to lose these changes.');
  }
}
```

And in my component class:

```js
@HostListener('window:beforeunload')
canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
  return false;
  // insert logic to check if there are pending changes here;
  // returning true will navigate without confirmation
  // returning false will show a confirm dialog before navigating away
}
```

## This all works fine! But...

In the component I am using, there is a navigate condition:

```js
this.router.navigate(['/thank-you', 'ads', res.data.slug]);
```

How can I let my app navigate to "/thank-you" without causing the "Warning" as at this point the form has been submitted.

Thanks

Comment: You can just insert in the `canDeactive` hostListener, logic to check if the form is being submitted. For sure you have a button for submitting the form, just set some private field `formBeingSubmitted` to `true` when it's clicked and then check for it the logic. Would that work?

Comment: Possibly, can you make an answer? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just insert in the `canDeactive` hostListener, logic to check if the form is being submitted.
If you have a button for submitting the form, just set some private field `formBeingSubmitted` to true when it's clicked and then check for it in the logic.

```js
private formBeingSubmitted = false;
@HostListener('window:beforeunload')
canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
  if(this.formBeingSubmitted){
  return true
  }
  return false;
  // insert logic to check if there are pending changes here;
  // returning true will navigate without confirmation
  // returning false will show a confirm dialog before navigating away
}

public onSubmit(){
  this.formBeingSubmitted = true;
}
```