# Angular CanDeactivate Router Guard with an Observable Subscribed Value

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-router, angular-router-guards

I've been trying to write a canDeactivate guard to check a saving state from an observable stream and work accordingly.

My service goes as this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs/ReplaySubject';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class EditModelService {

  private savingModelDataSource = new ReplaySubject<boolean>();

  savingModelData$ = this.savingModelDataSource.asObservable();

  public setSavingModelData(state: boolean) {
    this.savingModelDataSource.next(state);
  }

}
```

My guard goes as

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanDeactivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { EditModelService } from './edit-model.service';

@Injectable()
export class EditModelCanDeactivateGuardGuard {
  private savingState: boolean;

  constructor(
    private editModelService: EditModelService
  ) { }

  CanDeactivate(
    currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    currentState: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    this.editModelService.savingModelData$.subscribe(saving => {
      this.savingState = saving;
    });


    if (this.savingState) {
      return this.editModelService.savingModelData$.first();
    } else {
      return this.editModelService.savingModelData$.first();
    }

  }
}
```

Basically, it takes the value of the savingState from the service and returns according to the state so the router's canDeactivate attribute receives a boolean.
Since the value this.savingState in the guard is always subscribed I don't think there is an issue with the conditional goes below.

With some search I came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38524236/5476757) and tried doing the guard code as

```
return this.editModelService.savingModelData$.first();
```

Of course, I've imported first() here as `import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';`.

It returns an observable from the guard just to see whether that is working fine or if that is something to do with the way I am returning. But, in both of the scenarios, I get the error as shown in the image below.

[image]

I've provided the router guard inside the module where the router configuration is imported. That's where the service is provided as well.

What am I doing here wrong? I am new to using router guards(especially, canDeactivate with an observable) and any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you imported the authguard service under providers?

Comment: Yes. Provided inside the module where the router configuration is imported. That's where the service is also provided. @Sajeetharan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Guard Service must implement function to fully implement that **`CanActivate` or `CanDeactivate`**  interface. Try changing as

**From**

```
@Injectable()
export class EditModelCanDeactivateGuardGuard {
```

**To**

```
@Injectable()
export class EditModelCanDeactivateGuardGuard  implements CanActivate, CanDeactivate<boolean>{
```

also your **`CanDeactivate`** should be changed to **`canDeactivate`**

```
 canDeactivate() {

 }
```

**Updated after trying out the solution**:

Also, change

**From**

```
canDeactivate(
    currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    currentState: RouterStateSnapshot
): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean ...
```

**To**

```
canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean...
```

Comment: My bad. I had to remove the `currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot` `currentState: RouterStateSnapshot` parsed to `canDeactivate()`. Now it works fine. Thanks a million man!