# Return A boolean Promise from a function, to be used in the CanActivate function [Angular Guard]

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, guard, canactivate

I want to return a boolean promise from this function, any help please?

```
 getSectionsList() {
let sections: string[] = [];
var ref = this.db.database.ref(`instructors/jDlPCWMMJ8YmD9tMO3shTshM5sx1/sections`);
return ref.once('value').then(function (snap) {
  var array = snap.val();
  for (var i in array) {
    var value = array[i];
    sections.push(value.section)
    //console.log(value.section)
  }
  if (sections.includes('SPRING_2018_CMPS333_L01'))
    return (true)
  else
    return (false)

}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err)
})
```

}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49027861/angular-candeactivate-router-guard-with-an-observable-subscribed-value/49029611#49029611

Comment: sorry, but this is not related to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try injecting the AngularJS $q service...

```
if (sections.includes('SPRING_2018_CMPS333_L01'))
  return $q.resolve(true);
else
  return $q.resolve(false);
```

you can also $q.reject(false)

Comment: Thank you very much ! Solved the issue