# canDeactivate with Observable

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am implementing the router guard with canDeactivate method. It does not work if I return a async Observable.

The following steps that I did.

Created guard

```
@Injectable()
export class DeactivateGuardService implements CanDeactivate<CanComponentDeactivate> {
    canDeactivate(component: CanComponentDeactivate) {
            return component.canDeactivate() || window.confirm('Are you sure?');
          }
    }

export interface CanComponentDeactivate {
        canDeactivate: () => Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean;
      }
```

implemented the method in component.ts

```
canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean{
   return of(false);
   // return false;
 }
```

It is working fine, If I return false but It is not working if I return of(false).

Please suggest.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38524161/return-observable-in-candeactivate-not-working

Comment: why you need to return return of(false) ? instead of false

Comment: In real time, It would be HTTP call that returns the same.